# How to ignore undefined variables passed to the print function?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
help1 = 14
help2 = "nice"
help3 = "gate"

try:
    print('''
    help1 %d
    help2 %s
    help3 %s
    help4 %s
    ''' % (help1, help2, help3, help4))
except (NameError):
    print("")
```

I would like my `print` to reference multiple variables, some of which aren't defined (such as `help4`). How can I amend the print statement to skip any undefined variables? I tried with a `nameError` exception - but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Please detail what "couldn't get it to work" means.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? This smells very strongly of an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), and whatever you're actually trying to do, there's probably a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're not even getting to the `print` here. You can't reference undefined variables. Doing so raises a `NameError`. So you get to the `NameError` before the tuple of four values can even be created.

(Well, I suppose you could do something horrible with a chain of 10 `except NameError:` blocks that go through all the possible permutations of what could be wrong, but… eww…)

If you really need to do something like this, you have to manually look the names up indirectly in whichever namespace you think they should be in. For example, if this code is inside a function, and all four variables are supposed to be locals, you can look them up by name in the local namespace:

```
[locals().get(name, 'not found') for name in ('help1', 'help2', 'help3', 'help4')]
```

And likewise for globals, or any other namespace.

But this is almost certainly a bad idea. You should probably be doing something like:

- Assign default values to all of these variables at the top of the function/module/whatever, so they aren't undefined variables.
- Put these values in a list or a dictionary instead of in a bunch of separate variables that may or may not exist. (Notice that the hacky solution means you're already effectively doing this, except that you're hiding the dictionary away from yourself.)
- Keep track of the state more carefully so you know which variables you can use at any given point.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to check if a var exists, you can do

```
if "var_name" in locals():#or globals()
     print(var_name)
```

But this is usually not a good approach.

Comment: A better approach would be to use `try/except` to determine if `var_name` can be referenced without an exception..